# Android application works when debugging but won't install

Tags: android, debugging, xamarin, installation, android-4.4-kitkat

i'm developing an android application using Xamarin.Android.
It's all fine when installing my signed apk on an Android Kitkat phone, but when I try to install it on older android versions, there come the problems...
If I try installing the application on Android 4.1.2, it says "Application not installed", but if I try to debug the app using that phone as target it works brilliantly, no problems at all, every feature is working as expected. I also tried on android 4.2.2 and got the same result, so I think it's not related to minumum API level too low (it's set to 14 right now).

Is there any way I can see why it won't install?
Can anyone help me understanding the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: was there an instance of the app already installed on phone, when you were installing it?

Comment: No, it was first time!

Comment: How do you install it? Any error during installation?

Comment: I copyed the apk to the internal memory and tried to install it using both Astro and ES File Manager. It just says "Application not installed"

Comment: I have an update: if I compile the apk without signing it, it installs without any problem!
So you would think that the keystore is not working well... but on kitkat the signed apk is working

Comment: Does the devices which you have issues with have `Unknown sources` option enabled in the Settings -> Security menu?

Comment: I also faced this issue, but finally the url answer helped me lot.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/44387533/1404798

Answer (score 1):

Like Alex.F said, you may need to enable "allow unknown sources" in the settings menu. Other than that you may have added "uses-feature" attributes to your androidmanifest.xml that forbid the app to be installed on certain devices (in release mode).

For instance if you add

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
```

You shouldn't be able to install/start the app on devices that do not support usb-host mode. To remedy this you can add a required="false" attribute like so:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" android:required="false" />
```

This will make the usb-host feature optional. Hope that helps, otherwise see if you can try to provide a bit more information!

Good luck!