# Android App Installation Failed: Package com.my.app has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, installation, keystore

in Android Studio I generated a signed APK with keystore and so on. While installing the APK onto a device it fails with 'App could not be installed' and in Android Monitor I saw the following line:

```
Package com.my.app has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml; ignoring!
```

Does anybody know what's wrong?

Comment: Which signed apk version you are using for signing apk? V1 or V2? In which android os you are installing signed APK?

Comment: @AndyDeveloper I chose V2. The device is running Android 4.2.2.

Comment: Try to signed your apk with v1. V2 version signed apk only compitable from 7.0 so it will not working on below 7.0 devices or try to generate v1 and v2 version apk. Your issue will resolve.

Comment: Awesome dude! Thank you! What a stupid mistake I made  Please post this as answer, so I can mark it as solved.

Comment: welcome. See my updated answer.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> **Try to signed your APK with version 1. Version 2 signed APK only
> compatible from 7.0 so it will not working on below 7.0 devices or try
> to generate v1 and v2 version APK.**
>
> *[ Note: When you generate signed apk for above 7.0 devices and below 7.0 devices then please check v1 and v2 both option. ]*

Here is the [reference link for more about V2 version](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/v2) and here is the [link for overview](https://source.android.com/security/apksigning/).

Try this out and Your issue will resolved.