# Signed apk crashed using jsoup but debug does not

Tags: android, jsoup

Can any solve my problem?
I used Jsoup for version check from play store. When i run my application as debug apk from android studio. it works good. But when generate Signed Apk. It crashed when this code is run and message displayed "Unfortunately app is stopped". Is there any one who help me. I show you my code. Thanks in advance.

```
 private void getCurrentVersion(){
        try {
            currentVersion = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
        } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        new GetLatestVersion().execute();
    }

public class GetLatestVersion extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            latestVersion = Jsoup.connect("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + MainActivity.this.getPackageName() + "&hl=it")
                    .timeout(30000)
                    .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; WindowsNT 5.1; en-US; rv1.8.1.6) Gecko/20070725 Firefox/2.0.0.6")
                    .referrer("http://www.google.com").get().select("div[itemprop=softwareVersion]").first().ownText();
            return latestVersion;
        }catch (Exception e){
            return latestVersion;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String version) {
        super.onPostExecute(version);
        if(version!=null) {
            if (!currentVersion.equals(latestVersion)){
                showUpdateDialog();
            }
        }
        else
            dialog.dismiss();

    }
    public boolean isFinished() {
        return true;
    }
}

private void showUpdateDialog(){
    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("A New Update is Available");
    builder.setPositiveButton("Update", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse
                    ("market://details?id=com.kjsdeveloper.sattagamblers")));
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setNegativeButton("Later", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setCancelable(false);
    dialog = builder.show();
}
```

Comment: The problem is with your signed apk. [Check this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44387533/5860777) and you got the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add proguard Rule in proguard-rules.pro file located at Gradle Script
:

```
-keep public class org.jsoup.** {
    public *;
}
```