# Android : App not installed

Tags: android, game-development, godot

Newbie here.....I made my first game with Godot game engine and exported to android successfully.....copied to my phone, it installs and runs fine. After a couple of hours, I made some changes and exported it again.....Again copied the apk but now when I try to install it, It does not complete installation. I tried to change the export settings so many times but it wont install. Please help.

Tried installing using adb and I get this:

```
C:\Users\Suhail\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools>adb install -r .apk
adb: failed to install .apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Package /data/app/vmdl1790547402.tmp/base.apk has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml]
```

I am using jarsigner from oracle jdk 10(the latest version), and the debug keystore was created by the same jdk.
My device runs on Android 8.0

I downloaded APK Editor on my phone.....chose my apk….. and tried different 'install location' settings inside it. It was by default on Auto (OS Make Decision)…..changed it to 'Internal only'......still did not install...….changed it to Default(Not Specified) and it installed and works fine.
So does all this help my case any bit? I should not have to use APK Editor every time after exporting.
Thanks for your time anyways

When I try one-click deploy in Godot:

```
Exception occurred while executing:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown package: org.godotengine.dangerousplane
    at com.android.server.pm.Settings.getInstallerPackageNameLPr(Settings.java:5053)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.getInstallerPackageName(PackageManagerService.java:27945)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.isOrphaned(PackageManagerService.java:27951)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.deletePackageVersioned(PackageManagerService.java:24078)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageInstallerService.uninstall(PackageInstallerService.java:996)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.runUninstall(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:912)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerShellCommand.onCommand(PackageManagerShellCommand.java:134)
    at android.os.ShellCommand.exec(ShellCommand.java:96)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onShellCommand(PackageManagerService.java:28755)
    at android.os.Binder.shellCommand(Binder.java:581)
    at android.os.Binder.onTransact(Binder.java:481)
    at android.content.pm.IPackageManager$Stub.onTransact(IPackageManager.java:3211)
    at com.android.server.pm.PackageManagerService.onTransact(PackageManagerService.java:5111)
    at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:682)
Installing into device (please wait..): Samsung SM-A520F
running cmdline: "C:/Users/Suhail/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe" "-s" "5210d5c5e2787409" "install" "-r" "C:\Users\Suhail\AppData\Local\Temp/Godot/tmpexport.apk"
adb: failed to install C:\Users\Suhail\AppData\Local\Temp/Godot/tmpexport.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Package /data/app/vmdl2125437658.tmp/base.apk has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml]
running cmdline: "C:/Users/Suhail/AppData/Local/Android/Sdk/platform-tools/adb.exe" "-s" "5210d5c5e2787409" "shell" "am" "start" "-a" "android.intent.action.MAIN" "-n" "org.godotengine.dangerousplane/org.godotengine.godot.Godot"
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cmp=org.godotengine.dangerousplane/org.godotengine.godot.Godot }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {org.godotengine.dangerousplane/org.godotengine.godot.Godot} does not exist.
```

I just want to enjoy making games but this Android is giving me a headache.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android App Installation Failed: Package com.my.app has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386464/android-app-installation-failed-package-com-my-app-has-no-certificates-at-entry)

Comment: Did you compile from a different computer ? Or change the key? You can uninstall the current one and then install the new one

Comment: Doing a rebuild worked for me.

Answer (score 42):

> Go to /data/local/tmp in your your device folders [Like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TpacA.png).
>
> Delete the folder with your package name.
>
> Rebuild/clean & build project.
>
> Click on run

Comment: Restart your device and rebuild the project.

Comment: Invalidate the Android Studio and cleat build folder it works

Answer (score 2):

It happen to me recently and i could not find the app folder inside  /data/local/tmp.

i solve this by

- build apk
- transfer apk to phone and install from there
- uninstall the app on phone
- try run back from android studio

Comment: you are my god)))) really

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when i tried to install older version of apk while the latest version is still active.

Fix: Check the versions of the app and increment the version in your build.gradle file,

```
android {
..
..
defaultConfig {
..
..
versionCode <increment the version here>
..
..
}
..
}
```

Uninstall the older version and Install this version upgraded apk 
-or-
This upgraded apk will get installed on top of any old

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution I discovered that

The phone memory is full and you should free up some memory space

Answer (score 1):

- Go to developer option from your setting and switch to ON
- Make USB debugging option ON
- **Make Install via USB option ON**
  [image]

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same issue trying to install an application on Android emulator with insufficient free space on the internal phone memory. After uninstalling of a couple other apps this error have been disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**
In my case I encountered this error after following:
 1. I have created a copy of source folder.
 2. The original folder was lying there itself.
 3. when I opened this folder as android project and tried to run the app, it threw this msg.
 4. I simply changed the original folder name and new folder's name to original. The error was gone.

**Solution 2:**
Import project from current folder as new.

Answer (score 0):

after spending some hours i found the solution as follows:

1. Run uninstallAll from Gradle app > Tasks > install > uninstallAll (Check the picture)
2. Then install on to device. (Problem Remains)
3. Then Uninstall & install from Android Studio. Solved.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> I deleted the build folder and rebuild the project again.
>   After rebuilding the project, the apk was installed easily.

Answer (score 0):

If the above steps don't work, you can also try this:-

switch to "guest user" in your mobile device and search if old version of the app is available. If it is available, uninstall it.

Sometimes, even after uninstalling the app from the device, it's still remain installed in the guest session of the device.

This might work.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me when I copied the project from linux to mac.
Below steps worked for me:

1. Build clean the project
2. Hit run