# Android Studio: Unknown failure: Exception occurred while executing:

Tags: android, android-emulator, apk

I've researched articles on this and nothing seems to work. I am trying to run the code with an emulator. All the data is wiped on the emulator.

When i run the code on the emulator I get an error:

[image]

When I click OK. I get this error:

[image]

I am unsure how to get rid of this message. Any help?

Things done so far:

- [Android : App not installed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060284/android-app-not-installed)
- Also have changed package details
- [Change Android Package](https://www.google.com/search?q=change%20andriod%20package&rlz=1C1GGRV_enUS749US749&oq=change%20andriod%20package&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.3331j1j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#kpvalbx=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you tried below steps -

- Turn off **Instant Run** feature from settings(File ~> Settings ~> Build, Execution, Deployment).
- Perform a **clean build**.
- Turn on Instant Run feature from settings.
- Perform a clean build.
- `Invalidate Cache/ Restart` from `menu` option

Note :- If you have any device connected with system then disconnect first.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio Settings (if you are on windows)/Preferences (if you are on macOS) > Build, Execution, Deployment > Instant Run > Uncheck : Enable Instant Run.

Answer (score 2):

This colud also happen if you run out of storage,
so **make sure You have enough free storage on your device** before running the app.