# That's failed when I use command adb install to install apk which generated by the command ./gradlew assembleRelease

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk

I use `./gradlew assembleRelease` or the gralde task `assembleRelease` to generate apk, and then use `adb install xxx.apk`, the command shows

`adb: failed to install /Users/Documents/xxx.apk: Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES: Package /data/app/vmdl44198340.tmp/base.apk has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml]`

```
signingConfigs {

        release {
            v1SigningEnabled true
            v2SigningEnabled true
            storeFile file('/Users/Document/test.jks')
            storePassword 'test123'
            keyAlias 'test'
            keyPassword 'test123'
        }
}
```

Comment: Posible duplication question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386464/android-app-installation-failed-package-com-my-app-has-no-certificates-at-entry/44387533#44387533

Comment: look the signingConfigs, I open v1 and v2, install failed also.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android App Installation Failed: Package com.my.app has no certificates at entry AndroidManifest.xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44386464/android-app-installation-failed-package-com-my-app-has-no-certificates-at-entry)