# Installation did not succeed when running it on emulator

Tags: android, build, apk

I am updating somebody else's code and the following error is coming when i am running the build through android studio

```
Installation did not succeed.
The application could not be installed: INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_NO_CERTIFICATES

List of apks:
[0] '...\01\app\build\intermediates\extracted_apks\release\out\base-arm64_v8a_2.apk'
[1] '...\app\build\intermediates\extracted_apks\release\out\base-en.apk'
[2] '...\app\build\intermediates\extracted_apks\release\out\base-master_2.apk'
[3] '...\app\build\intermediates\extracted_apks\release\out\base-xxhdpi.apk'
APK signature verification failed
```

I have run it through gradle and then installed the apk on my phone and its working but its not working on emulator directly. The minSdkversion is fine. I changed it

**UPDATE:**
Here is my build file:

```
android {
   
         
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.abc.xyz"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 6
        versionName '1.6'

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        //for one signal app id
        manifestPlaceholders = [onesignal_app_id               : "XXXX",
                                onesignal_google_project_number: "XXXX"]

        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {

            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'


//            firebaseCrashlytics {
//                nativeSymbolUploadEnabled true
//            }
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.onesignal:OneSignal:3.+@aar'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2+'
    //  implementation 'com.onesignal.OSNotificationOpenResult:3.8.3'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:21.0.1'
    // Realm
   // implementation 'io.realm:realm-android:0.82.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:1.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.7.5'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
// Import the BoM for the Firebase platform
    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:26.4.0')
      
    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.3.1'

    // Recommended: Add the Google Analytics SDK.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:18.0.2'

    // Add the Firebase Crashlytics NDK dependency.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics-ndk:17.3.1'

}
repositories {
    mavenCentral()

}
```

Comment: can you share your build.gradle file

Comment: @ZIRES I have updated my question with the build file

Comment: Try to signed your APK with version 1. Version2. see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44387533/12280908

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to enable v2 signature scheme in your signing configuration:

You should have

```
v2SigningEnabled true
```

for all the flavours in the `signingConfigs` blocks.

Comment: No I have mentioned it but its not working. I have updated my question with my build file please check